# getting a EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x0) error

Tags: ios, objective-c, exc-bad-access

I am getting a bad access error in my code and I don't why.

Here's my code

```
-(IBAction)datePickerValueChanged:(UIDatePicker *)sender{
    myDatePicker = [[myDatePickerView subviews] lastObject];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setLocale:sender.locale];
    [dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
    activeTextField = (UITextField *) [self.view viewWithTag: *(tag)];
    [activeTextField setText:[dateFormatter stringFromDate:[sender date]]];
}
```

P.S: I created the activeTextField property in the @interface, like so

`@property (nonatomic,strong) UITextField *activeTextField;`

And I synthesized it

`@synthesize activeTextField;`

Comment: What is this `*(tag)`?

Comment: On which line it breaks excaclty and what is *(tag) ?

Comment: tag is a property of UIView, @property (nonatomic) NSInteger *tag;

Comment: it breaks on: activeTextField = (UITextField *) [self.view viewWithTag: *(tag)];

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace this line

```
activeTextField = (UITextField *) [self.view viewWithTag: *(tag)];
```

with

```
activeTextField = (UITextField *) [self.view viewWithTag: tag];//tag should be an integer
```

Comment: To clarify @Bhumeshwer's answer, placing a star in front of an evaluated expression dereferences a pointer. Since tag is most likely an integer (and not a pointer to an integer), dereferencing it will have some nasty side effects.

Comment: tag is a NSInteger not an int

Comment: @iOSMaster:`NSInteger` is not an object; it is a typedef of `int` either 32-bit or 64-bit depending on the processor.